# NLP - Extracting complete phrases

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

I want to extract **complete** [linguistic phrases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phrase) from an input sentence.

A phrase is defined [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B3nZV6_wNSY) as:

> A group of words that belong together as a unit, they fill a single clause within a larger structure (like a clause or another phrase) and can't be further broken up and moved around separately

For example (borrowed from phrase source):

**Given the sentence:** "The excited students thanked the visiting teacher from an overseas university after the inspiring lecture"

**Expected output:**
"The excited students", "thanked the visiting teacher from an overseas university", "after the inspiring lecture"

Alternate output (might be technically incorrect): "The excited students", "thanked the visiting teacher", "from an overseas university", "after the inspiring lecture"

Using spaCy, I can get the syntactic dependencies, but I don't know how to recreate phrases out of those (or if that is even possible)

PyTextRank output only gives key phrases, which cannot be used to recreate the full phrase. This example gives the following output: "the inspiring lecture", "an overseas university", "the visiting teacher", "The excited students"

Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: what do you mean by *complete phrase* and why is "the excited students" one, but not "the visiting teacher"?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: The problem with this is that it's hard to define "complete phrases" in a way that always works. Like if you had "The excited students and some guy" is that one phrase or two? If two, where does "and" go? You'll need to make or find definitions and implement them. You might want to look at "sentence simplification", which has some similar problems.

Comment: @KonstantinosKokos Either phrase composition works for me, so I will update the question with more details. I borrowed the example from here: https://youtu.be/B3nZV6_wNSY?t=56

Comment: @polm23 Thanks for the suggestion, I will definitely check out sentence simplification. I tried clarifying the question. re: your question, I believe the "and" is a coordinating conjunction joining two nouns, making it a single phrase

Comment: @KonstantinosKokos To further clarify, my ultimate goal is to get the correct linguistic phrases, but suggestions that get me close to this are still appreciated, even if technically not a correct phrase

Comment: What you describe is *constituency parsing*. Check out the relevant literature and software. Voting to close as off-topic.